# Android getting error Ksoap in android 4 or above

Tags: android, ksoap2, android-ksoap2, ksoap

My application could running in android 2.* without any problem and that can correctly use `KSoap` module. but after installing app in Android 4 or above i get this error:

```
627-627/ir.tsms E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
            at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:71)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:351)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:86)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:308)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:303)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:282)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:80)
            at org.ksoap2.transport.ServiceConnectionSE.connect(ServiceConnectionSE.java:46)
            at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:68)
            at ir.tsms.wsdl.WSDLHelper.call(WSDLHelper.java:34)
            at ir.tsms.wsdl.TSMS.checkUserAuth(TSMS.java:64)
```

My `WSDLHEPLER` is:

```
public class WSDLHelper {
    public static String call(SoapObject request) throws TException {
        String result;

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        AndroidHttpTransport transport = new AndroidHttpTransport(Strings.URL_TSMS);
        transport.debug = true;

        try {

            /*  GETTING ERROR IN BELOW LINE  */
            transport.call(Strings.URL_TSMS + request.getName(), envelope);
            result = envelope.getResponse().toString();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.e("" , ex.getMessage());
            throw new TException(PublicErrorList.NOT_EXIST_ERROR_DETAIL);
        } catch (XmlPullParserException ex) {
            Log.e("" , ex.getMessage());
            throw new TException(PublicErrorList.NOT_EXIST_ERROR_DETAIL);
        }
        if (result.equals(String.valueOf(Integers.CODE_USER_PASS_FALSE)))
            throw new TException(PublicErrorList.USERNAME_PASSWORD_ERROR);

        return result;
    }

    public static String convert1(String str) {
        return str.substring(1, str.length() - 1);
    }

    public static String[] convert2(String str) {
        return str.split(", ");
    }

    public static String[] convert3(String str) {
        return str.split(",");
    }

}
```

after testing in android 2.2,3,3.* not problem. i dont know why this module could not running in android 4. please help me. thanks

my `Ksoap` is :

```
ksoap2-android-assembly-2.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the other answer does not work, then try this in your onCreate method,

```
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Answer (score 0):

LogCat tells you whats wrong :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

You are Networking on your `MainThread` , in Android 3.0 and above you have to do Networking on Background Thread.

**Edit** : this is just an example and it might contain errors!

```
public class WSDLHelper  extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/***";
//private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/***";
private static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static String METHOD_NAME = "yourMethodName";
private String Url;

private Context context;

public WSDLHelper()
{

}

public WSDLHelper(Context context)
{
    this.context = context;
}


@Override
public void onProgressUpdate(String... data)
{
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... uri) 
{
        publishProgress("prepare sending");
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);     


        request.addProperty("YourKey",Key);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        new MarshalDate().register(envelope);

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.implicitTypes= false;

        try {
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(url);
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.
            SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
            String Test = result.toString();
            String Test1 = result.getProperty(0).toString();
            publishProgress("data accepted - " + result.getProperty(0).toString());
            return result.getProperty(0).toString();


            } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
            }

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    super.onPostExecute(result);

    if("OK".equals(result) )
    {
        // Do What you Want
    }
    else
    {
    }
}
```

}

Comment: hi. i dont have any networking on app.or any action sush as `Thread` i have only check network access to internet. whats your exactly mean? move `ksoap` on `Thread`?

Comment: @MahdiPishguy : you are consuming a Ksoap webservice and make a request to a server , so you are Networking. you should do this on another thread or using AsyncTask.

Comment: can you help me to how to use AsyncTask ? my main request and using `Ksoap` pasted on post. thanks